# Why does my Pi NoIR camera stop working at 23:59?

Tags: camera

It's working the whole day but during the night it stops at 23:59

Somebody knows why?

My crontab looks like

```
30 19 * * * ./raspiLapseCam.py & 
30 06 * * * sudo pkill python 
45 06 * * * ./raspiLapseCam2.py & 
00 19 * * * sudo pkill python
```

And the script can be found here: https://bitbucket.org/fotosyn/fotosynlabs/src/0a5f212958637ce20f502fc579fc28338b33d87e/RaspiLapseCam/raspiLapseCam.py

Comment: What is working, and stops working? The camera? The _hardware_? How do you know it stopped working?

Comment: to work taking pictures (timelapse - each minute). It' due to work from 7pm to 7am. Each day it is taking pic from 7pm and stop at 23:59. ???

Comment: Ok. But how do you know it stops working at 23:59?

Comment: I get pictures every minutes from 7 PM andt it's scheduled to go on up to 7AM. Date and time are shown on the picture. Without any other command in crontab...There is no picture after 23:59

Comment: Would you please post the crontab line and any script you use to realize this?

Comment: Crontab :30 19 * * * ./raspiLapseCam.py &
30 06 * * * sudo pkill python
45 06 * * * ./raspiLapseCam2.py &
00 19 * * * sudo pkill python

Comment: @Bex
crontab:
30 19 * * * ./raspiLapseCam.py &
30 06 * * * sudo pkill python
45 06 * * * ./raspiLapseCam2.py &
00 19 * * * sudo pkill python

The script coud be found here:
https://bitbucket.org/fotosyn/fotosynlabs/src/0a5f212958637ce20f502fc579fc28338b33d87e/RaspiLapseCam/raspiLapseCam.py

The difference between raspiLapseCam and raspiLapseCam2 is only some of the camera options for daylight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't stop working. The script will save the files into a folder named after what time it started.

See line 67:

```
folderToSave = "timelapse_" + str(initYear) + str(initMonth) + str(initDate) + str(initHour) + str(initMins)
```

That means that the script does not stop working - you just have an offset in the folders.